# making jQuery Dialog to wait for post back or JavaScript prompt allowing custom html

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, asp.net-4.0

I want to prompt the user with possible values (which I've got stored in JavaScript array ) to be displayed as radio buttons to choose if some value in text-box is left empty and user clicks on 'Save' telerik's Rad Ribbon Bar button laying in master page.

> **My problem is, when I click on Save, the server side method does not
>   wait for the jQuery UI Dialogue to close, I tried a while loop saying
>   *wait here till the dialogue box disappears* but that spiked abruptly & hung up my page** :-(

---

- For my scenario, we're importing data from other application so, can;t use the on change event
- We'e the requirement : While saving prompt the box with available values, get the selected value and continue saving with selected value, so I can not add a button, hide it and trigger .click() event
- my client may not welcome "return false;" they just want to continue saving

I've got following working

1. Client side event handler gets called from content page when save button is called
2. the above JavaScript function checkes if value is empty
3. Getting available values from server side and storing in array
4. creating html and on the fly (code below)

Code Snippet 1 ( to declaring div for jQuery UI dialogue in content page)

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/JQueryUI/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../Scripts/JQueryUI/css/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<link href="../Scripts/JQueryUI/css/smoothness/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

---

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Tracking #">
    <span style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0; z-index: 999999 !important"></span>
    <p>
    </p>
</div>
```

Code Snippet 2 ( fires client side function when Click event triggers on Save )

```
function onSave(sender, args) {
var sButtonText = args.get_button().get_text();
if (sButtonText == "Save") {
    var
        trackingIDs = $('#<%=_tbPrevtrackerID.ClientID %>').val(),
        $trackerIDInputControl = $('#<%= tbtrackerID.ClientID %>'),
        currenttrackerIDValue = $trackerIDInputControl.val(),
        trackerIDs = trackingIDs.split(',').clean(''), //Extension Method
        noOftrackerIDsAvailable = trackerIDs.length,
        markup = 'trackerID is empty : <br/><br/><input type="radio" name="trackerIDGroup" value="" >Leave Empty</input><br/>';
    for (var i = 0; i < noOftrackerIDsAvailable; i++) {
        markup += '<input type="radio" name="trackerIDGroup" value="' + trackerIDs[i] + '">' + trackerIDs[i] + '</input><br/>';
    }

    if (currenttrackerIDValue == '') {
        $('#dialog-confirm').css({ 'display': 'block' });

        $("input:radio[name=trackerIDGroup]").click(function () {
            $trackerIDInputControl.val($(this).val());
            trackerIDChecked = true;
        });

        //Please note, if I'd use following it does work, but I am going to have multiple values
        //$trackerIDInputControl.val(prompt(markup, trackerIDs[0]));

        if ($("#dialog-confirm") != null) {            
            $("#dialog-confirm p").html(markup);
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 300,
                width: 300,
                closeOnEscape: false,
                modal: false,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function () {
                        if ($trackerIDInputControl.val() != '') { 
                            $('#dialog-confirm').css({ 'display': 'none' });
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $('#dialog-confirm').css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    }
                }
            }).parent().appendTo(jQuery("body form"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 Your question is not very clear. What is it that you actually want?

Comment: @Walter, I want two things

1st : When I click on Save, the server side method does not wait for the jQuery UI Dialogue to close, I want the server side postback to wait till user has selected a value from jQuery Dialogue If you've ever known telerik, it is possible by doing args.set_cancel(true); //args is the parameter as seen in fist line
 but then how can I replicate the click event ? sender.click() did not seemed to be working for unknown reason

Comment: 2nd : I want to get the seletected item's value from the radio button group that I dynamically added to jQuery's dialogue

Comment: my main point is, if somehow I can get the JavaScript prompt to have radio buttons ( check markup variable ... ) then whole problem would be sovled, but I think it's not possible so I am finding a way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Ajax Control Tool kit has something more suitable for you, please have a look at [this](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) demo.